# .NET core highly scalable zero-alloc sockets library

Tags: .net

Is there a .NET core library which implements scalable, zero-allocation client/server sockets?

I've seen certain benchmarks online (e.g. [web framework benchmarks from TechEmpower](https://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/#section=data-r18&hw=ph&test=fortune)) which compare various frameworks/stacks/OSes in different scenarios. There are also many articles and threads online which fall into several groups:

1. "Highly scalable server using `BeginReceive`/`EndReceive`"
2. "Highly scalable server using `SocketAsyncEventArgs`"
3. "Highly scalable server using `async`/`await`"

And it seems like each new framework version brings a new best way of doing things.

However, with the inclusion of `Span`, `Memory` and other extensions which avoid allocations, I still cannot find a .NET library which I am supposed to use when for connection to thousands of IoT devices, without creating a heavy burden on the GC or the needed system RAM.

Is there a .NET framework which can handle 10k connections, which uses IOCP under the hood, doesn't make new allocations on each received packet, and doesn't need gigabytes of RAM?